# What's the best way to extract Excel cell comments using Perl or Ruby?

Tags: ruby, perl, excel, parsing

I've been parsing Excel documents in Perl successfully with [Spreadhsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.44/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) (as recommended in [What's the best way to parse Excel file in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429193)), but I can't figure out how to extract cell comments.

Any ideas? A solution in Perl or Ruby would be ideal.

Comment: I am not sure if ParseExcel can be used for this but I am going to look into it. In the mean time, can you run this on Windows and do you have Excel installed? If both answers are yes, this can be done using Win32::OLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use Ruby's win32ole library.

The following (somewhat verbose) example connects to an open Excel worksheet and gets the comment text from cell B2.

```
require 'win32ole'

xl = WIN32OLE.connect('Excel.Application')
ws = xl.ActiveSheet
cell = ws.Range('B2')
comment = cell.Comment
text = comment.Text
```

More info and examples of using Ruby's win32ole library to automate Excel can be found here:

http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/search/label/excel

Answer (score 7):

The Python [xlrd](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.htm) library will parse cell comments (if you turn on `xlrd.sheet.OBJ_MSO_DEBUG`, you'll see them), but it doesn't expose them from the API.  You could either parse the dump or hack on it a bit so you can get to them programmatically.  Here's a start (tested extremely minimally):

```
diff --git a/xlrd/sheet.py b/xlrd/sheet.py
--- a/xlrd/sheet.py
+++ b/xlrd/sheet.py
@@ -206,6 +206,7 @@
         self._dimncols = 0
         self._cell_values = []
         self._cell_types = []
+        self._cell_notes = []
         self._cell_xf_indexes = []
         self._need_fix_ragged_rows = 0
         self.defcolwidth = None
@@ -252,6 +253,7 @@
         return Cell(
             self._cell_types[rowx][colx],
             self._cell_values[rowx][colx],
+            self._cell_notes[rowx][colx],
             xfx,
             )

@@ -422,12 +424,14 @@
                     if self.formatting_info:
                         self._cell_xf_indexes[nrx].extend(aa('h', [-1]) * nextra)
                 self._cell_values[nrx].extend([''] * nextra)
+                self._cell_notes[nrx].extend([None] * nextra)
         if nc > self.ncols:
             self.ncols = nc
             self._need_fix_ragged_rows = 1
         if nr > self.nrows:
             scta = self._cell_types.append
             scva = self._cell_values.append
+            scna = self._cell_notes.append
             scxa = self._cell_xf_indexes.append
             fmt_info = self.formatting_info
             xce = XL_CELL_EMPTY
@@ -436,6 +440,7 @@
                 for _unused in xrange(self.nrows, nr):
                     scta([xce] * nc)
                     scva([''] * nc)
+                    scna([None] * nc)
                     if fmt_info:
                         scxa([-1] * nc)
             else:
@@ -443,6 +448,7 @@
                 for _unused in xrange(self.nrows, nr):
                     scta(aa('B', [xce]) * nc)
                     scva([''] * nc)
+                    scna([None] * nc)
                     if fmt_info:
                         scxa(aa('h', [-1]) * nc)
             self.nrows = nr
@@ -454,6 +460,7 @@
         aa = array_array
         s_cell_types = self._cell_types
         s_cell_values = self._cell_values
+        s_cell_notes = self._cell_notes
         s_cell_xf_indexes = self._cell_xf_indexes
         s_dont_use_array = self.dont_use_array
         s_fmt_info = self.formatting_info
@@ -465,6 +472,7 @@
             nextra = ncols - rlen
             if nextra > 0:
                 s_cell_values[rowx][rlen:] = [''] * nextra
+                s_cell_notes[rowx][rlen:] = [None] * nextra
                 if s_dont_use_array:
                     trow[rlen:] = [xce] * nextra
                     if s_fmt_info:
@@ -600,6 +608,7 @@
         bk_get_record_parts = bk.get_record_parts
         bv = self.biff_version
         fmt_info = self.formatting_info
+        txos = {}
         eof_found = 0
         while 1:
             # if DEBUG: print "SHEET.READ: about to read from position %d" % bk._position
@@ -877,13 +886,23 @@
                 break
             elif rc == XL_OBJ:
                 # handle SHEET-level objects; note there's a separate Book.handle_obj
-                self.handle_obj(data)
+                obj = self.handle_obj(data)
+                if obj:
+                    obj_id = obj.id
+                else:
+                    obj_id = None
             elif rc == XL_MSO_DRAWING:
                 self.handle_msodrawingetc(rc, data_len, data)
             elif rc == XL_TXO:
-                self.handle_txo(data)
+                txo = self.handle_txo(data)
+                if txo and obj_id:
+                    txos[obj_id] = txo
+                    obj_id = None
             elif rc == XL_NOTE:
-                self.handle_note(data)
+                note = self.handle_note(data)
+                txo = txos.get(note.object_id)
+                if txo:
+                    self._cell_notes[note.rowx][note.colx] = txo.text
             elif rc == XL_FEAT11:
                 self.handle_feat11(data)
             elif rc in bofcodes: ##### EMBEDDED BOF #####
@@ -1387,19 +1406,16 @@


     def handle_obj(self, data):
-        if not OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
-            return
-        DEBUG = 1
         if self.biff_version < 80:
             return
         o = MSObj()
         data_len = len(data)
         pos = 0
-        if DEBUG:
+        if OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
             fprintf(self.logfile, "... OBJ record ...\n")
         while pos < data_len:
             ft, cb = unpack('<HH', data[pos:pos+4])
-            if DEBUG:
+            if OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
                 hex_char_dump(data, pos, cb, base=0, fout=self.logfile)
             if ft == 0x15: # ftCmo ... s/b first
                 assert pos == 0
@@ -1430,16 +1446,14 @@
         else:
             # didn't break out of while loop
             assert pos == data_len
-        if DEBUG:
+        if OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
             o.dump(self.logfile, header="=== MSOBj ===", footer= " ")
+        return o

     def handle_note(self, data):
-        if not OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
-            return
-        DEBUG = 1
         if self.biff_version < 80:
             return
-        if DEBUG:
+        if OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
             fprintf(self.logfile, '... NOTE record ...\n')
             hex_char_dump(data, 0, len(data), base=0, fout=self.logfile)
         o = MSNote()
@@ -1453,13 +1467,11 @@
         o.original_author, endpos = unpack_unicode_update_pos(data, 8, lenlen=2)
         assert endpos == data_len - 1
         o.last_byte = data[-1]
-        if DEBUG:
+        if OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
             o.dump(self.logfile, header="=== MSNote ===", footer= " ")
+        return o

     def handle_txo(self, data):
-        if not OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
-            return
-        DEBUG = 1
         if self.biff_version < 80:
             return
         o = MSTxo()
@@ -1477,8 +1489,9 @@
         rc3, data3_len, data3 = self.book.get_record_parts()
         assert rc3 == XL_CONTINUE
         # ignore the formatting runs for the moment
-        if DEBUG:
+        if OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
             o.dump(self.logfile, header="=== MSTxo ===", footer= " ")
+        return o

     def handle_feat11(self, data):
         if not OBJ_MSO_DEBUG:
@@ -1638,11 +1651,12 @@

 class Cell(BaseObject):

-    __slots__ = ['ctype', 'value', 'xf_index']
+    __slots__ = ['ctype', 'value', 'note', 'xf_index']

-    def __init__(self, ctype, value, xf_index=None):
+    def __init__(self, ctype, value, note=None, xf_index=None):
         self.ctype = ctype
         self.value = value
+        self.note = note
         self.xf_index = xf_index

     def __repr__(self):
```

Then you could write something like:

```
import xlrd

xlrd.sheet.OBJ_MSO_DEBUG = True

xls = xlrd.open_workbook('foo.xls')

for sheet in xls.sheets():
    print 'sheet %s (%d x %d)' % (sheet.name, sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols)
    for rownum in xrange(sheet.nrows):
        for cell in sheet.row(rownum):
            print cell, cell.note
```

Comment: @OP: remember that you could do this from Inline::Python in Perl, if you really wanted to!