# Read Excel Cell Comment using Python on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, excel

I am using `Python` in a Linux (Ubuntu) environment.

How do I go about reading the  **comment** that is stored in cell `A5` in spreadsheet `MyFile.xls` (in case it matters, this file in in `Excel 2003` format)?

Comment: When you did a Google search for reading XLS files in Python, what were the first few links?  Which of those open source projects looked good to you?  Do you have a specific question on how `xlrd` works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was going to say that it's too bad that [`xlrd`](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.htm) doesn't handle comments, but then I stumbled upon this [What's the best way to extract Excel cell comments using Perl or Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826617/whats-the-best-way-to-extract-excel-cell-comments-using-perl-or-ruby).

Key passage:

> The Python xlrd library will parse
>   cell comments (if you turn on
>   xlrd.sheet.OBJ_MSO_DEBUG, you'll see
>   them), but it doesn't expose them from
>   the API. You could either parse the
>   dump or hack on it a bit so you can
>   get to them programmatically.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: thank you. Can you perhaps provide an example how to do this? I know how to use `xlrd`, yet am not sure how to implement the changes you suggested.

Comment: @user3262424  There's the rub.  It doesn't work out of the box and requires some mucking about -- more than I'm prepared to do for an answer.  If you refer to the answer I linked to you will see that much of the work has been done for you, you just have to learn how to read a diff.

Comment: @user3262424   If this is too difficult you might need to pay someone to do it.  Or perhaps you could see if this capability exists in excel libraries for ruby or perl or something.  Or you could automate openoffice to open the file and extract the comment.

Comment: @user3262424  Ruby's parse excel has a member of the cell object called "annotation".  That sounds like a comment.  See http://rubydoc.info/gems/parseexcel/0.5.2/frames.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: thank you. I will take a closer look on this. Also, what happens if I switch Excel with OpenOffice? Is there a python module that would read comments that are in an OpenOffice spreadsheet?

Comment: @user3262424  The python module for OpenOffice is called `uno`.  I think it's crap--it's both unwieldy and unintuitive.  I included it in my answer merely for completeness.  I think the `xlrd` hack is your best option.  I'd be happy if someone else came up with a better answer.

Comment: You can use sheet.cell_note_map to read comments, don't know when that was added, but its easy as can be, no DEBUG paresing or anything. Its just there.

Comment: @i_4_got: Nice catch.  Looking at source and revision history `cell_note_map` was added in version 0.7.2 which was released 2012-01-14.

Answer (score 3):

You can read Notes by using [sheet.cell_note_map](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.cell_note_map-attribute) easy.