# Perl/Bash: Echo the value of an specific .XLS cell to a text file

Tags: perl, xls

I have a .XLS table, where each cell has a value of pure text (with newlines).
I need to use bash/perl to echo the value of a specific cell (by row and column number) to a text file.
Idea of script:

`inputxls="$1"
column="$2"
row="$3"
outputtextfile="$4"`

Calling script:
script table.xls 5 3 celltext.txt

the output to to the text file would be:

`foo
bar
bar
foo`
(respecting new lines)

This is to work with a .xls populated with only text, there is no need to work with math.
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to parse Excel file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429193/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-excel-file-in-perl).  Note that this is an old question, but if it really is XLS, not XLSX, it's still correct.  There are other modules out there, too.

Comment: I can't find in that answers how to output an specific cell (by row and columm number).

Comment: The top answer includes a complete working example that gets data from a specific cell. Hint: the relevant function is called get_cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::Read;



  sub get_cell {
  # send the file the sheet and the cell as 
  # command line arguments
    my ($file, $sheet, $cell) = @ARGV;
    return 0 unless $file =~ /.*\.xls/i;
    my $book = ReadData ($file);
    return $book->[$sheet]{$cell};
 }

    my $output_file = 'test.txt';

    open (FH, '>>', $output_file) or die "Canoot open ' $output_file' $!";
    print FH get_cell();
```